# Why is output of parent process blocked by child process?

Tags: c++, fork

In my code below, I forked my process into a parent and child process. In the child process, I sent the c string argv[1] to the parent process to be printed. Then I made the child process sleep for 4 seconds before printing "This is the child process. Closing\n".

In the parent process, I want the string from the child process to be printed to stdout as soon as I receive it from the child process.

The problem arises here. Instead of immediately printing argv[1] in the parent process before the string "This is the child process. Closing\n" is printed 4 seconds later, what happens is this:

$ g++ -std=c++11 printchild.cpp -o printchild

$ ./printchild helloworld

1) 4 seconds passes

2) "This is the child process. Closing\n" is printed

3) "helloworld" is printed

Why is the output from the parent process blocked by the child process?

```
// printchild.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  int pipefd[2];
  pid_t cpid;
  if(argc != 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if(pipe(pipefd) == -1){
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  cpid = fork();
  if(cpid == 0){
    close(pipefd[0]);
    FILE *fpc = fdopen(pipefd[1],"wb");
    fprintf(fpc,"%s",argv[1]);
    fflush(fpc);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
    fprintf(stdout,"This is the child process. Closing\n");
    return 0;
  }else if(cpid == -1){
    perror("Error in forking");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }else{
    char str[80];
    close(pipefd[1]);
    FILE* fp = fdopen(pipefd[0], "rb");
    fgets(str,80,fp);
    fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",str);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent process is reading the child's message via `fgets()`.  It will continue to read until one of three things happens:

- enough bytes have been read to fill the buffer, less one for a string terminator
- a newline is read
- end-of-file is encountered

The child does not send enough bytes to exhaust the buffer, and it does not send a newline, so the parent's `fgets()` does not return until the child's end of the pipe is closed upon its exit.

You can fix this in the child by having it either terminate the message with a newline or close the stream immediately after writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you close the file in the client right after flushing, it will work as expected:

```
fflush(fpc);
fclose(fpc);
```

Output:

```
[dbush] /tmp/x1 hello
hello
[dbush] This is the child process. Closing
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the `fgets` call.
It tries to fulfill your request fully, and that's the cause of the blocking.

If you're prototyping some IPC, I recommend you ditch `stdio` and go for the raw `IO` syscalls.

If you substitute, e.g.:

```
char buf[100];
read(pipefd[0], buf, 100);
fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",buf);
```

for the `fgets` part, you'll get your message right away, because `read` will give you whatever's available and return (if there's at least 1 byte in the pipe buffer at the time you make the `read` request), whereas `fgets` won't back off until it has read all the requested bytes or until it figures out it can't (EOF or an IO error).

(To split hairs, it's not `fgets` that's blocking (userspace code alone can't block) -- it's another momentarily unsatisfiable `read` syscall that `fgets` has issued).